# Defining custom helper class in laravel issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have created a folder called 'library' in Laravel `app` directory.
Then added a line to the following class in  `global.php`.

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path() . '/library',

));
```

Then I did `php artisan dump-autoload`

But when I do this, it throws an error that the class is not defined:

```
$SMS = new sendSMS();
```

Comment: Please can you also include the directory structure in `library`, particularly the path to the file that your `sendSMS` class lives in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in your composer.json file, there is an autoload section in there. Add the path in question to that section, run `php artisan dump-autoload` and you should be good to go.